# How to remove whitespaces in R

Tags: r

Build a condition to check if all the numbers in a vector marks greater than 90. If yes then assign string "Best Class" to the variable ans, else assign "Needs Iprovement".

```
classmark<-function(marks){

ans<-c(marks)
for(i in seq_along(ans))
{
if(ans[i]>90)
{
    ans[i]="Best Class"
}else
{
    ans[i]="Needs Improvement"
}
}

return(trimws(ans))
}
print(classmark(c(100,95,94,56)))
print(classmark(c(100,95,94,96)))
```

Output I am getting is

```
"Best Class"    "Best Class"     "Best Class"  
"Needs Improvement"
"Best Class" "Best Class" "Best Class" "Best Class"
```

Comment: Hi! What is your desired output? You don't want the outputs in the same line?

Comment: I want to remove whitespaces which I am getting in output.

Answer (score 1):

There is no question about trimming whitespace here even if the question title suggests that.

> to check if **all** the numbers in a vector marks greater

R has an `all` function for that:

```
classmark <- function(marks){
  if (all(marks>90)){
    return("Best Class")
  }
  return("Needs Improvement")
}

print(classmark(c(100,95,94,56)))
print(classmark(c(100,95,94,96)))
```

Comment: Or in one line : `ifelse(all(marks>90),'Best Class','Needs Improvement')`

Comment: If it solves your problem please click to "accept the answer". That will mark it as solved to others.